# Blackberry - Sort ListField data by date

Tags: sorting, blackberry, labelfield, pubdate

I have got data from XML parsing, and try to sort it based on date which has format like "Wed, 06 Jun 2012 09:53:05 +0700". So all news from every provider will be mixed and organized from the latest to the newest.

Here is the code:

```
int i=0;
while (i<vec.size()){

    row = new TableRowManager();

    prov = new LabelField(((BinNews)vec.elementAt(i)).getProv(),DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS){
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGERED);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    title = new LabelField(((BinNews)vec.elementAt(i)).getTitle(),DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS){
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };
    title.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD));

    desc = new LabelField(((BinNews)vec.elementAt(i)).getDesc(),DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS){
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    date = new LabelField(((BinNews)vec.elementAt(i)).getDate(),DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS){
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGERED);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    rows.addElement(row);
    setSize(rows.size());
    row.add(prov);
    row.add(date);
    row.add(title);
    row.add(desc);
    i++;
}
```

so, before I add it into the row, it will be sorted first. Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you tried simple sort vector ?.

Comment: i've never tried it before. is that any simple explanation or reference about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

```
public static SimpleSortingVector  vector = new SimpleSortingVector ();


vector.setSortComparator(new MyComparator());
vector.addElement(new FriendsRequestObject(id_,name_));
vector.reSort();    



import net.rim.device.api.util.Comparator;
public class MyComparator implements Comparator {
 public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    FriendsRequestObject f1 = (FriendsRequestObject)o1;
    FriendsRequestObject f2 = (FriendsRequestObject)o2;

    return f1.getSender_name().compareTo(f2.getSender_name());
  }

  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return compare(this, obj) == 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: actually it's only sorting based on the alphabet and time, how if i want to sort based on it's day too?